Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' error spring boot
When I compile my spring project, I got the following error.

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]

im using h2 for database.
My
application.properties
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect



pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hashim</groupId>
    <artifactId>rusik</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rusik</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2024.0.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



Based on the exception that you provided, the only way I managed to reproduce it is when I did NOT HAD ( or in your situation you did had that dependency but you did not pull dependencies using maven ).
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

And since you had for some reason MySQL dependency as well and you are stating that you are using h2 database, I would advise you to do the following.
Remove the MySQL dependency
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>

And after that make sure that you pull your dependencies again by running command in your terminal
mvn clean install

Or right-click on your Project / pom.xml Maven > Reload or Maven > Update depending on your IDE.
What is important is that you make sure to use Maven to pull the dependencies you mentioned in your pom.xml because Maven will not do that by default.
Another thing I'd like to mention is that I've tested while the project has h2 and MySQL dependency at the same time, and it does not throw an exception, so with that in mind please make sure that you pull h2 dependency by using one of the ways mentioned above.
To confirm that you did pull dependency into your project from Maven you can run the following command
mvn dependency:tree

and in your terminal it will list all your dependencies that are present in your project looking like this
[INFO] --------------------------< com.hashim:rusik >--------------------------
[INFO] Building rusik 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.33 has been relocated to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33: MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ rusik ---
[WARNING] The artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.33 has been relocated to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33: MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.
[INFO] com.hashim:rusik:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring6:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.25.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.17:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-bom:pom:2024.0.1:import
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.3.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:6.0.6.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye:jandex:jar:3.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:6.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.2.224:runtime
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.29.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] \- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.599 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-26T17:50:16+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you look closely maven listed h2 dependency with the following line
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.2.224:runtime

If you do not have this line in your tree command, that means that you did not pull your h2 dependencies from maven repository.

Thank you for your detailed answer, but my problem is not solved.

Have you pulled dependencies and reran your project while having only h2 dependency in your pom.xml?

`PS C:\Users\hashi\Workspace\rusik> mvn clean install
mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

mvn clean install

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mvn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`



bro i got it at terminal -> mvn clean install .Can it be reason for my problem?

If you do not have maven installed the mvn command will not work. What Spring does when it generates your project it also creates .mvn folder inside that is a maven wrapper, in order to use maven wrapper you can use mvnw instead of mvn. You can test if your maven wrapper is present by trying to execute the command 'mvnw -version' IN the folder where your .mvn folder is, which is your "rusik" project folder.

Here is an example of the command ( it is executed in folder rusik because that is your project folder that has .mvn folder )

C:\Users\hashi\Workspace\rusik>mvnw -version

Make sure that you execute these mvnw commands from terminal of your windows, not terminal of your IDE

i got this error : mvnw : The term 'mvnw' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

mvnw -version

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mvnw:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.2.224:runtime i got it . so it is not about depencies ? @zawarudo

now i fixed all mvn problems,H2 is connected,but mvnw doesn't have yet

So when you run your project with that dependency present in your project are you getting the same exception still? There was no need for the change in the code that you shared besides removing MySQL dependency and pulling dependency again.

as for mvn or mvnw, if you have maven you can use mvn command, if you do not have maven but you have .mvn folder in your project, then you can use mvnw, it is the same thing the only difference is that you use either real maven with mvn, or maven wrapper with mvnw

i reinstalled maven and did all configurations. Still there is same entityManagerFactory error ..

If that is the case you will need to provide how someone can reproduce that issue while having h2 dependency present in your project. The only way I managed to reproduce your exception was while you were NOT having h2 dependency pulled from maven. So please provide the minimal reproducible example of that exception while having h2 dependency in your project, because I tried using the code that you provided and the issue is not present.

"First of all, as you mentioned, the main reason of the error was related to Maven, where there were some missing configurations that I completed. The exact reason for the error was that 'User' is a reserved keyword in H2 database. I resolved the issue by changing the table name and specifying the table name under @Entity. This solved the problem.I offer you my gratitude. Have a good day!
